# SQL query with filters

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run a SQL query but I'm not sure how to accomplish. So I have the following query that outputs the below results:

```
SELECT
    events.Name, results.Description, Events.Id, 
    results.EventId, results.UserId
FROM
    Events
LEFT JOIN 
    Results ON events.Id = Results.EventId
```

[image: Query Results:]

What I'm trying to do is filter out `UserId = 66` and the associated `eventId`. So the results table should exclude rows with `UserId = 66` and rows with `EventId = 4`.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: But you do want to still get the row with `UserId = 66 and EventId = 9` ? Or do you want to filter out **all** rows with `UserId = 66` (and *any* `EventId`)? Not totally clear. ...

Answer (score 0):

> So the results table should exclude rows with UserId 66 and rows with EventId 4.

Well, you may want:

```
SELECT e.Name, r.Description, e.Id, r.EventId, r.UserId
FROM Events e JOIN
     Results r
     ON e.Id = r.EventId
WHERE r.UserId <> 66 AND e.eventId <> 4;
```

This would appear the answer the question that I've quoted.  However, your query is using a `LEFT JOIN` and other parts of your question are somewhat ambiguous.

For instance, if you want these removed fro your specific query:

```
SELECT e.Name, r.Description, e.Id, r.EventId, r.UserId
FROM Events e LEFT JOIN
     Results r
     ON e.Id = r.EventId AND e.eventId <> 4
WHERE r.UserId <> 66 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but is there a way to query this without having to hardcode the '4' eventId. To clarify I'm trying to do is filter out the 4 or 9 events without having to explicitly state it or code it. So it should know to exclude event ID '4' or '9' because userId 66 is associated with those records.